# How to freeze session timout in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, session, spring-security

I'm setting the session timeout in the application properties

```
server.servlet.session.timeout=10m
```

But I want to change it when the user in specific pages is there any method to do it?

Comment: I don't think you can do that for any specific since this is a container-based setting.

Comment: You could let your page do a ping-request within the timeout-range.